# no index in root, redirect to other folder?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to redirect to a login.php that is not in my root folder, but in a other folder.

For example: my root contains:

- production
- index.php

In production there is a login.php. How can I send the user to this page when they go to my domain (with the application) instead of the index.php in the root?

Regards, Bart

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` to redirect users **IF** you want to redirect **ALL** visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simply send an HTTP header using the PHP `header()` function so that the client would redirect:

```
<?php header("Location: production/login.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your `index.php`:

```
header('location: /production/login.php');
```